# Responsive Multi-Level Menu

Tags: jquery

I've found a very good mobile menu and it works great, but I need help to create more than 1 menu, 2 or 3. I've downloaded the menu from

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/04/19/responsive-multi-level-menu/

If someone has a demo with 2 or more menus, please let me know so I can see where I made a mistake.

If anyone can help me I would be very grateful.

Comment: what's up with the German language?

Comment: Hi everybody, I've found a very good mobile menu and funksioniert great, but I need your help I need to create more than 1 menu 2 or 3 but I can not do the menu I downloaded from this link the menu


http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/04/19/responsive-multi-level-menu/

if someone has a demo with 2 or more menu has, if possible, please send then I see where my error lies

if anyone can help me I defend very grateful